# Wrap one right-floated element underneath another

Tags: html, css, position, divider

I'm trying to put 2 divs beneath each other like this:

```
div 1
div 2
```

This is how far i've gotten in the HTML-file:

```
<div width="100%" z-index:"1">
            <div id="username-full">

                <div id="username-form">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username-input" placeholder="Username" />
                </div>

                <div id="username-text">
                    <p>Username:</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div width="100%" z-index:"1">

            <div id="passwd-full">

                <div id="passwd-form">
                    <input type="text" name="passwd" id="passwd-input" placeholder="passwd" />
                </div>

                <div id="passwd-text">
                    <p>Password:</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

And this is my CSS-file:

```
#username-full{
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
#username-text{
    float:right;
    margin-right:5px;
}
#username-form{
    float:right;
    margin-top:13px;
}

#passwd-full{
    text-align:right;
    float:right;

}
#passwd-text{
    float:right;
    margin-right:5px;
}
#passwd-form{
    float:right;
    margin-top:13px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/f1g2kmho/)**

As you see, i've tried using the z-index, i've tried to give the 2 divs a width of 100% and i tried using float. Also, I've tried using positioning, but that also didn't work. I'm out of guesses :(.

Greetings,
Luuk

Comment: [OFF] Try to "experimenting" bootstrap. Its easier to adjust position of your input fields and you will get a responsive site. =)

Comment: `width` and `z-index` are not valid properties of a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing, but have a look at this:

```
#passwd-full {
    ...
    clear: right;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/f1g2kmho/1/)**

Comment: I did use that, but I had put it in the wrong place, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, try adding this line:

```
#passwd-full{
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two divs 100% with each and one above the other, you should try:

```
<div id="One">My first content</div>
<div id="Two">My second content</div>

#One, #Two {width: 100%; clear: both;}
```